# How do I execute symbolic linked files in node.js?

Tags: node.js, require, symlink

I'm writing an application that contain a skeleton directory that would be copied to a new node project. Since I'm debugging the skeleton, I'm symlinking the file in my new folder,
so:

```
mainapp/skel/index.js

sampleapp/index.js -> ../mainapp/skel/index.js
sampleapp/package.json
sampleapp/node_modules/abc
```

index.js:

```
require('abc');
```

But running the sampleapp with:

```
node index.js
```

are not working because it seems to try to find the module in mainapp/skel/node_modules instead of sampleapp/node_modules. Any idea for a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options -

1. Symlink `node_modules` directory in `skel`
2. Set NODE_PATH environment variable
   `export NODE_PATH=<path_to_sampleapp_node_modules>`